# How best to split Spring Boot service/repository tier off into a separate Maven project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, modularity

I am working on a Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf templates for views, as well as Java classes in three "tiers": Controller, Service, and Repository.  I would like to move the Service and Repository tiers into a separate Maven project (I'm calling it "service-tier") that the "View/Controller" application can pull in as a dependency.

The reason for this is that I expect to use the same service/repository/database logic for other, future applications with different audiences.  I don't have the green light to go to a (micro)service architecture with separate *running programs* for the front-end and back-end, but I can separate the *code* and unite it at build time.

**What's the best way to separate out just the Services and Repositories?**  Here are some specific points to clarify, but there may be other questions I haven't figured out that I need to ask:

- What starters and dependencies do I need in the service-tier artifact's POM? `spring-boot-starter-parent`? `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`?  The database driver?
- Do the `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations do anything for me if they're in the service-tier artifact?
- Do I need a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the "service-tier" project, for example to run tests?  How about the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`? (The latter seems to prevent the "`mvn install`" phase.)
- Where do I put my data source properties such as the JDBC URL?  In `application.yml` in the service-tier, or in the UX tier project that depends on it?

Pointers to working code that is divided up in this way would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, this is what I ended up with, and it works:

The `service-tier` is a Maven project containing `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations.

- It contains the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, `spring-boot-starter-security` dependencies, as well as the database driver.  Some test-scoped dependencies, too: JUnit, `spring-boot-starter-test`, and `spring-security-test`.  This is almost all the dependencies that the front-end application uses, minus Thymeleaf and some Webjars artifacts.
- I don't know if the annotations do anything for me or not, but I kept them in.
- After way too long, I remembered that Maven projects have a `test` directory for classes and resources that will only be used in testing and not bundled with the packaged JAR or WAR.  In that directory structure I put a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, as well as `application.yml` with database connection info.  This is used in running integration tests, and doesn't affect the web applications that depend on the service tier.

The front-end applications are their own Maven projects.  In each of them:

- They declare `service-tier` as a dependency.
- They also declare all the Spring Boot dependencies.  Many are redundant but that's not a problem with Maven.  Additional dependencies include `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` and a couple of other Thymeleaf dependencies, as well as a few dependencies from org.webjars that include Bootstrap and JQuery.
- They *also* have their own `@SpringBootApplication` annotated classes and `application.yml`.  These are the "real" configurations, not just test configurations.
- All `@Controller` classes as well as Thymeleaf templates and static files and `messages.properties` are in these front-end projects.
- Spring Security configuration (i.e. `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instances) are in these projects.  (The `UserDetailsService` is in the service-tier, though.)

It works pretty smoothly as long as I make sure that the front-end applications always call the latest version of `service-tier`.

**One interesting complication** is that a Spring Boot application will only scan for service and repository classes within its own Java package.  Initially I had the service tier in a package hierarchy like "`com.mycompany.servicetier`" and the front ends in packages like "`com.mycompany.appone`" and "`com.mycompany.apptwo`".  I had to move the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in each front-end project one level higher, to "`com.mycompany`", so it would discover the service tier classes "below it" for dependency injection.